# VBA to fill blank cell with Null using usedrows in worksheet

Tags: excel, vba

I have a workbook with 44 columns,I need to filter non blanks from column no. 44 and from 1st column i want to select blanks and fill it with "null" (I don't want to use find and replace).

Below is my code that I tried.

```
Dim Xrow As Long, WS As Worksheet, dng As Range
Xrow = Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

With ActiveSheet
     Set WS = ActiveSheet
     Set dng = .Range("A2:A" & Xrow)
     WS.Range("A1:AR1" & Xrow).AutoFilter Field:=44, Criteria1:="<>"

     WS.Range("A1:AR1" & Xrow).AutoFilter Field:=1, Criteria1:="="
     Range("A1").Select
     ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select

     Do Until ActiveCell.EntireRow.Hidden = False
         ActiveCell.Offset(1, 0).Select
     Loop

     dng.SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible).Value = "Null"
     Range("A1:AR1").AutoFilter

End With
```

Comment: Are you encountering errors / what exactly doesn't work?

Comment: Welcome to SO. Try to bring a minimum set of information: input sample, expected output sample, what did you try and your research. With just the code it is not possible to see your problem and help you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From your question I'm not entirely sure what the end result is supposed to look like, but from the way the code is written there is only one possible interpretation. This code will put `"Null"` into all empty cells of column 1 that have a non-empty cell in column 44 of the same row. This is a more straightforward approach.

```
Dim lastrow As Long
Dim cll As Range
Dim ws As Worksheet

Set ws = ActiveSheet
lastrow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each cll In ws.Range("A2:A" & lastrow).SpecialCells(xlCellTypeVisible)
    If ws.Cells(cll.Row, 44).Value2 <> vbNullString And cll.Value2 = vbNullString Then
        cll.Value2 = "Null"
    End If
Next cll
```

Comment: with your first code:-
If the last cell of column A is empty then it is not getting replace with "null" but if in between some cells are empty then they are getting replaced  by null.

With your second code
all the cells of column A are getting replace by null.

Desired out put should be:
In column A if some cells are empty but in rest of columns if there are values then blanks should be replaced by "null".
For Example if cell B15 is having some value and A15 is blank then A15 should be replaced by null.

Comment: @ManishYemde I adjusted my code. You're right, one necessary check was missing, to see if the cell in column `A` is actually empty.